# align two columns on a review page

Tags: html, css

I make a review page that has 5 stars, just to the left of each is text. I want to align each column evenly so that the stars are in align as well as the text in line. Here is an image and as you can see there are all un even, is there an easier way to align them ? I tried manually lining them up by either added padding to the left or right, some of the text on the left hand side is longer than other so it makes it a messy formula. If anyone has any idea that would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rate {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rate1 {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate1:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate1:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate1:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate1>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate1:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate1:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate1>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate1>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate1>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate1>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate1>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}

{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rate2 {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate2:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate2:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate2:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate2>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate2:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate2:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate2>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate2>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate2>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate2>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate2>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}

{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rate3 {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate3:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate3:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate3:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate3>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate3:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate3:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate3>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate3>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate3>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate3>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate3>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}

{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rate4 {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate4:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate4:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate4:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate4>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate4:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate4:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate4>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate4>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate4>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate4>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate4>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Star rating using pure CSS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

  <br><br>
  <center>
    <h1 style="font-family: " Montserrat ", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI ", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue ",
        Arial, "Noto Sans ", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji ", "Segoe UI Emoji ", "Segoe UI Symbol ", "Noto Color Emoji "">Please rank us below</h1>
  </center>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="flex">
    <p id="paragraph" style="color: #0d0d0d; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; font-family: " Lato ", Arial,
        sans-serif;">Results</p>
    <div class="rate" style="padding-left: 365px">
      <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
      <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
      <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
      <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
      <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
      <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <p id="paragraph" style="color: #0d0d0d; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; font-family: " Lato ", Arial,
        sans-serif;">Communication</p>
    <div class="rate1" style="padding-left: 300px">
      <input type="radio" id="star10" name="rate1" value="5" />
      <label for="star10" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star9" name="rate1" value="4" />
      <label for="star9" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star8" name="rate1" value="3" />
      <label for="star8" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star7" name="rate1" value="2" />
      <label for="star7" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star6" name="rate1" value="1" />
      <label for="star6" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <p id="paragraph" style="color: #0d0d0d; padding-right: 65px; font-weight: bold;  font-size: 20px; font-family: " Lato ", Arial, sans-serif;">Website</p>
    <div class="rate2" style="padding-left: 305px">
      <input type="radio" id="star15" name="rate2" value="5" />
      <label for="star15" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star14" name="rate2" value="4" />
      <label for="star14" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star13" name="rate2" value="3" />
      <label for="star13" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star12" name="rate2" value="2" />
      <label for="star12" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star11" name="rate2" value="1" />
      <label for="star11" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <p id="paragraph" style="color: #0d0d0d; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; padding-right: 10px; font-family: " Lato ", Arial, sans-serif;">Response Time</p>
    <div class="rate3" style="padding-left: 305px">
      <input type="radio" id="star20" name="rate3" value="5" />
      <label for="star20" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star19" name="rate3" value="4" />
      <label for="star19" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star18" name="rate3" value="3" />
      <label for="star18" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star17" name="rate3" value="2" />
      <label for="star17" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star16" name="rate3" value="1" />
      <label for="star16" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <p id="paragraph" style="color: #0d0d0d; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; padding-left: 200px font-family: " Lato ", Arial, sans-serif;">Customer Service</p>
    <div class="rate4" style="padding-left: 300px">
      <input type="radio" id="star25" name="rate4" value="5" />
      <label for="star25" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star24" name="rate4" value="4" />
      <label for="star24" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star23" name="rate4" value="3" />
      <label for="star23" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star22" name="rate4" value="2" />
      <label for="star22" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star21" name="rate4" value="1" />
      <label for="star21" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Comments</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 30%" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox for the alignment rather than trying to calculate a specific padding to line the sections up:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: " Montserrat ", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI ", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue ", Arial, "Noto Sans ", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji ", "Segoe UI Emoji ", "Segoe UI Symbol ", "Noto Color Emoji";
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: " Lato ", Arial, ans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.rate {
  position: relative;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Star rating using pure CSS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<h1>Please rank us below</h1>

<div class="flex">
  <p>Results</p>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p>Communication</p>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star10" name="rate1" value="5" />
    <label for="star10" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star9" name="rate1" value="4" />
    <label for="star9" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star8" name="rate1" value="3" />
    <label for="star8" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star7" name="rate1" value="2" />
    <label for="star7" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star6" name="rate1" value="1" />
    <label for="star6" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p>Website</p>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star15" name="rate2" value="5" />
    <label for="star15" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star14" name="rate2" value="4" />
    <label for="star14" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star13" name="rate2" value="3" />
    <label for="star13" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star12" name="rate2" value="2" />
    <label for="star12" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star11" name="rate2" value="1" />
    <label for="star11" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p>Response Time</p>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star20" name="rate3" value="5" />
    <label for="star20" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star19" name="rate3" value="4" />
    <label for="star19" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star18" name="rate3" value="3" />
    <label for="star18" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star17" name="rate3" value="2" />
    <label for="star17" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star16" name="rate3" value="1" />
    <label for="star16" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p>Customer Service</p>
  <div class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star25" name="rate4" value="5" />
    <label for="star25" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star24" name="rate4" value="4" />
    <label for="star24" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star23" name="rate4" value="3" />
    <label for="star23" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star22" name="rate4" value="2" />
    <label for="star22" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star21" name="rate4" value="1" />
    <label for="star21" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of logical and practical problems up there.

- IDs must be unique, otherwise they don't identify anything. This is an HTML spec requirement.
- Repeating style blocks for each element would be a dev and maintenance nightmare. Classes are sets of like things. Combine them.
- Inline styles are even worse. Why would you have a stylesheet, then crud up your markup with separate styling?
- [The `center` element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center?retiredLocale=it). Don't use it. In your case, Bootstrap provides [text alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/text/#text-alignment) anyway, along with [flex alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/).
- Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's a misuse. Use margin or padding instead (or flex layout). Bootstrap has some nice [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/).
- Style blocks with no selector don't do anything.
- Don't direct users to somewhere with words like "below". That's just clutter. Instead, make your UI intuitive.

Here's all that cleaned up, with some Bootstrap flex utility classes applied for layout. I don't exactly know what layout you're looking for, so feel free to comment.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
  font-family: " Montserrat ", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI ", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue ", Arial, "Noto Sans ", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji ", "Segoe UI Emoji ", "Segoe UI Symbol ", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

p {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: " Lato ", Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.rate {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
}

#exampleFormControlTextarea1 {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">Please rate us!</h1>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-4">
    <p>Results</p>

    <div class="rate">
      <input type="radio" id="star5a" name="rate" value="5" />
      <label for="star5a" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4a" name="rate" value="4" />
      <label for="star4a" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3a" name="rate" value="3" />
      <label for="star3a" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2a" name="rate" value="2" />
      <label for="star2a" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1a" name="rate" value="1" />
      <label for="star1a" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-4">
    <p>Communication</p>

    <div class="rate">
      <input type="radio" id="star5b" name="rate" value="5" />
      <label for="star5b" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4b" name="rate" value="4" />
      <label for="star4b" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3b" name="rate" value="3" />
      <label for="star3b" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2b" name="rate" value="2" />
      <label for="star2b" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1b" name="rate" value="1" />
      <label for="star1b" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-4">
    <p>Website</p>

    <div class="rate">
      <input type="radio" id="star5c" name="rate" value="5" />
      <label for="star5c" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4c" name="rate" value="4" />
      <label for="star4c" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3c" name="rate" value="3" />
      <label for="star3c" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2c" name="rate" value="2" />
      <label for="star2c" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1c" name="rate" value="1" />
      <label for="star1c" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="mr-2">Comments</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```